# "Can't find table" error in SQL FROM(UNION) AS table, INNER JOIN, COUNT() FROM table

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, inner-join

I currently have a query where inside each union select, in order to get a count of occurences, I had something like:

```
SELECT Order_Id, Order_Date, 
       C.cnt AS Order_Parts
  FROM table1
  INNER JOIN (SELECT Order_Id, count(Order_Id) as cnt
                 FROM table1
                GROUP BY Order_Id) C ON table1.Order_Id = C.Order_Id
UNION SELECT Order_Id, Order_Date, 
       C.cnt AS Order_Parts
  FROM table2
  INNER JOIN (SELECT Order_Id, count(Order_Id) as cnt
                 FROM table2
                GROUP BY Order_Id) C ON table2.Order_Id = C.Order_Id
```

And it worked alright, but I'm reorganising it so that the UNION is inside the Query FROM, so something like this:

```
SELECT
Order_Id,Order_Date,C.cnt AS Order_Parts

FROM(
    SELECT Order_Id, Order_Date
    FROM table1
    UNION SELECT Order_Id, Order_Date
    FROM table2
) AS Parts
    INNER JOIN (SELECT Order_Id, count(Order_Id) as cnt
                FROM Parts
                GROUP BY Order_Id) C ON Parts.Order_Id = C.Order_Id
```

But Access throws me an error saying it can't find table or query 'Parts'. I can't for the life of me figure out why it can't use it; could someone guide me to what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems pretty clear.  A table alias (i.e. `parts`) refers to a table or reference for the purpose of defining columns.  It does provide a new "source" for data.

That is, it cannot be reused as a table in the `from` clause.

This is true in all databases.  However, just about any other database supports common table expressions -- which do what you want.  MS Access does not.  Your only options are:

- Repeat the `UNION` query for the second reference.
- Use a view.

Note:  There might be other approaches to writing the query that you want to write.  For that, I would suggest that you ask a *new* question with sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want to accomplish.

Also, you may not want `UNION` because that removes duplicates.  `UNION ALL` is more common.

Comment: Oh Gosh of course. Thank you! Yes, I may at some point have to write a new question with the overall aim. UNION should be ok I think in this instance as each table has a completely different format for Order_Id (I'm combining order details from Ebay, Etsy and some others into one) but I should probably get into a habit of UNION ALL anyways...

Comment: @Eireni'Fikia'Moutoussi . . . I might suggest that you switch to a more standard database.

Comment: I ah, don't know what you mean by that, I don't know what is standard as I'm just figuring things as I go along for the small business I work at. I have 0 training in IT, I'm actually just hired originally for marketing/graphic design, but the manual paperwork was driving me nuts so decided to learn some database stuff and my bosses didn't disagree. But I have since reorganised so it doesn't look like this any more, again... I'm sure this is probably cause to wince for you...